# Replies are not consumed from reply queue

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I'm sending messages with InOut pattern to a JMS queue and set the replyTo to a predefined queue. 
sometimes everything works fine and sometimes camel wont read replies from that queue and fail with TimedOutException. 
sometimes I can see  2 or more consumers on the reply queue  (using AMQ web console) but camel wont consume it.

When I see one consumer on the reply queue (using AMQ web console),  everything works fine
and when I see many consumers on the reply queue (using AMQ web console), camel wont read replies from that queue and fail with TimedOutException.

Environment : Fuse ESB

**Java Code**

```
from("activemq:spirit.adapter.producer.shippingorder.commands") 
.id("router-Shipping-Order-Commands") 
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Transport1", "router-Shipping-Order-Commands request: ${body}")
.to("activemq:transport.consumer.shippingorder.commands?replyTo=tra‌nsport.prod‌ucer.shippingorder.event&replyToType=Exclusive&requestTimeout=120000")‌​
.log(Logg‌​ingLevel.INFO, "Transport1", "router response: ${body}");
```

**activemq configuration**

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
<property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://10.10.40.94:61616"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="1" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
 </bean>


 <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
 </bean>

  <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
  </bean>
```

This configuration is written in the camel-context.xml file and in the same file there is another activemq configuration used for another route

could you please advise?

Comment: Why do you use topics for request/replies? Usually you would use a queue for that.

Comment: typing mistake, it's a queue

Comment: 2 or more consumers?? Are there any other application consuming your messages? Is your camel bundle started more than once? Otherwise, please post some code etc. for better answers.

Comment: No, the same application, there are not other applications consuming the messages, and the camel bundle started once,               **Java Code**                                   _from("activemq:spirit.adapter.producer.shippingorder.commands") .id("router-Shipping-Order-Commands") .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Transport1", "router-Shipping-Order-Commands request: ${body}")  .to("activemq:transport.consumer.shippingorder.commands?replyTo=tra‌​nsport.producer.shippingorder.event&replyToType=Exclusive&requestTimeout=120000")‌​.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Transport1", "router response: ${body}");_

Comment: Put the code in the question and make it readable. Then its easier for others to read and therefore also to help.

Comment: the code is added on the question

Comment: And you are also doing request/reply on the 1st queue, eg "spirit.adapter.producer.shippingorder.commands".

Comment: And what version of Fuse ESB are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All-
The problem was caused by some bugs in camel-jms 2.9.x which was shipped in Fuse ESB 7.0.1 and solved in Fuse ESB 7.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your activemq configuration you are using? For example make sure you configure the init and destroy methods on the pool so it can properly start|stop as documented here: http://camel.apache.org/activemq